# create a schema in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

How can I create multiple schema under a user defined DB in hive?

I am trying to create a schema under a DB sam_db in hive. I am using the folowing code.

```
use sam_db;
create schema sam_db_schema;
```

But when I visit the local host to see the filesystem I see that instead of a schema being created inside sam_db a db named sam_db_schema is getting created.

Below is the screen shot presenting my case:
[image]

Isn't multiple schemas for a DB not possible in hive.

If possible then how do I create them.

Are both database and schema same for hive. Because when I do a

```
show databases;
show schemas
```

It gives me the same output.

Please help me understand : Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Are both database and schema same for hive?

Yes. The [Language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterDatabase) states this clearly:

> ```
> CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) [IF NOT EXISTS] database_name
>  [COMMENT database_comment]
>  [LOCATION hdfs_path]
>  [WITH DBPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, ...)];
> ```
>
> The uses of **SCHEMA and DATABASE are interchangeable – they mean the same thing**